# Freezing cheesecake with strawberries

Tags: cheesecake

Can you freeze unbaked cheesecake with cut fresh strawberries mixing in the cheese mixture filling?

Comment: Why unbaked? I believe freezing them baked is pretty common.

Comment: It may be an unbaked cheesecake recipe (@catija) - not all cheesecakes are baked at all ([bbc recipe for strawberry cheesecake](http://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/4653/strawberry-cheesecake-in-4-easy-steps-)). strawberries don't freeze very well especially if they freeze slowly as they would here - when defrosted they tend to release a lot of juice.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you *can* freeze the cheesecake with fresh strawberries, but the problems lie when you try to defrost said cheesecake if you need to bake it, or even if you plan to eat it at a temperature other than frozen. Like Chris' comment above, when defrosting strawberries, then tend to exude a lot of juice, and in pastry making, you usually don't desire random wet patches. If you're planning to bake it, perhaps skip the fresh strawberries and put them in later as a topping. OR, you could always, mix in strawberries in another form, that has less problems with water content— pre-macerated, in a jam, or something like that.